# How to confirm the insert query is a success?

Tags: java

I am inserting into the database with foll0wing code and it's working fine as I can see the data populates in the db, however I want to capture the result programmatically whether it was a success or failure

1) Here is the code to insert

```
public void SignUp(String last_name, String first_name, String email,
        String password, String confirm_password, String phone) {

    Connect connect = new Connect();
    Connection conn = connect.Connection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL,('" + last_name + "'),('"
            + first_name + "'),('" + email + "'),('" + password + "'),('"
            + confirm_password + "'),('" + phone + "'))";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    conn.close();

}
```

2) Here is the code I used to connect

```
public Connection Connection() {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        String userName = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/project";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        System.out.println("\n Database connection established");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("\n Cannot connect to database server");

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to amuse me, try saving the name Shaquille O'Neal into your database. Then do some research on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> executeUpdate

```
public int executeUpdate(String sql)
                  throws SQLException
```

> Returns: either the row count for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements,
>   or 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Comment: On an Insert, do you know if it would return the rows affected or 0 since nothing was returned?

Comment: inserting a row will return a value greater than zero as long as the new record was entered successfully.

Comment: @JohnKane - I tried this in my example, but I didn't get the expected result, could you please put an example on this ?

Comment: @Srikanth an example of which?

Comment: on usage of `public int executeUpdate(String sql)
                  throws SQLException`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to query for it directly. Its always a good idea to [check the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29), but with an update I am not sure that barring an exception there is a clean way to tell if it was successful (other than a lack of exceptions being thrown).

As a side note, take a look at [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). It is generally not a good idea to use strait text when executing un-sanitized sql.